# Будет ли выгружена DLL из памяти при появлении исключения в экспортируемой функции?

Tags: windows, исключения, dll

Допустим есть DLL которая загружена в память и используется 2-мя процессами. В первом процессе при вызове экспортируемой функции из DLL возникает исключение.

1. Будет ли в таком случае доступна DLL из 2-го процесса?
2. Выгрузится ли DLL из памяти?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С чего бы вдруг она выгрузилась? Исключение относится к процессу, DLL тут не при чём. Она выгрузится, когда завершатся **все** использующие её процессы. Если вы таким хитрым образом пытаетесь повлиять на чужой процесс, то у вас ничего не выйдет.